# Node prepared statement: use LAST_INSERT_ID in second query with variable items

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am trying to write to two tables using two `INSERT` statements one after another.

The second `INSERT` statement should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` of the first statement. For this I assign the variable `@last_id_invoices`. How can I access that variable in a prepared statement when the number of rows to be written is variable?

The example code below uses static values, but the idea is that both `customer` and `items` will be coming from another script, thus it is not known how many `items` there will be.

Ideally `@last_id_invoices` in the `items` array would be interpreted as reference to the variable in the statement, rather than as a string, as it would be in the below example:

```
var customer = 123;
var items = [
    ['@last_id_invoices', 11],
    ['@last_id_invoices', 12]
];

var sql = "\
    INSERT INTO invoices (customer) VALUES (?);\
    SET @last_id_invoices = LAST_INSERT_ID();\
    INSERT INTO line_items (invoice_id, product_id)\
    VALUES ?;\
    ";

var inserts = [customer, items];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You can pass the variable to the second insert as follows:

```
var sql = "\
    INSERT INTO invoices (customer) VALUES (?);\
    SET @last_id_invoices = LAST_INSERT_ID();\
    INSERT INTO line_items (invoice_id, product_id) VALUES (@last_id_invoices, ?);\
    ";
```

Comment: thanks! I actually tried that, but as soon as I add parenthesis around the wildcard ( i.e. `...product_id) VALUES (?)` ) Node throws the error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. This doesn't happen if I do the same statement, but leave out the parenthesis (i.e. `...product_id) VALUES ?` ). Could this be some Node specific behaviour?